# Not getting whole email body if email have .ics calendar event attachment when i retrieving emails from gmail by IMAP in php

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I am not getting email body and also getting calendar event attached `.ics` file as a string and body is missing when I am retrieving emails with IMAP
`imap_fetchbody` function with php.

I have also used `imap_fetchbody($box, $messageNo, '1.2')`. I have also tried this with `1,2,1.1,2.1` but not find anything.

Please provide me solution of this.

Comment: Have you tried actually inspecting the MIME structure or BODYSTRUCTURE of the message?  Hardcoding the part number is never going to work for all messages.

Comment: When i have checked mail has Content-Type: multipart/mixed;

Comment: And the rest of it?  MIME can be complex structure, and parts can be anywhere.  Multipart/mixed means only it has subparts: what are the subparts?

Comment: what subparts can i give u. it has one calendar and other has text body

Comment: You could do lots of things: you could include the MIME message here, you could dump the BODYSTRUCTURE response...